# Can't see error messages when creating Drupal form in a separate file

Tags: 7, forms, status-messages

Suppose, I want to use Drupal libraries inside a separate php file to generate a form. I created 3 functions:

1. function add_form
2. function add_form_validate
3. function add_form_submit

And then used `drupal_get_form` / `render` to get the HTML code. But when I insert invalid data, I don't see the error message - just the red border of the text input. Here is the minimal example to reproduce the error (file is called test.php and is located inside Drupal directory):

```
<?php
//including Drupal libraries
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
require_once(DRUPAL_ROOT . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'includes'.  DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'bootstrap.inc');
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);

//form with 1 text field and submit button
function add_form($form, &$form_state)
{
    $form['text'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => 'Insert text',
        '#required' => true,
        '#attributes' => array('autofocus' => 'autofocus'),
        );

    $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => 'Submit',
        );

    return $form;
}

//text must be 'aaa'
function add_form_validate($form, &$form_state)
{
    if ($form_state['input']['text'] != 'aaa')
    {
        form_set_error('text', t('Text is not aaa!'));
    }
}

function add_form_submit($form, &$form_state)
{
    print "I am inside add_form_submit<br>";
    var_dump($form_state['input']);
    exit;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>element</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/modules/system/system.base.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/modules/system/system.theme.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/modules/system/system.messages.css">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" >
  </head>
  <body>
<?php
//here is the problem: I don't know, how to output the error message
print theme('status_messages');

$content = drupal_get_form('add_form');
$content = render($content);
print $content;
?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is working fine for me, only thing is that I get the error message only when submitting for the second time, that is because you are printing the `status message` before the `drupal_get_form()`. So if I print the message after `drupal_get_form()` then it is working as expected.